# Does using a laptop on your lap lower your sperm count?

Tags: medical-science, fertility, human-reproduction

It is sometimes claimed that using a laptop on or in proximity of testicles can result in a lower sperm count. This [Health.com](http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20344474_5,00.html) article claims:

> Can a laptop computer really affect a man’s ability to reproduce?
>   According to researchers at the State University of New York at Stony
>   Brook, there is a direct correlation between laptop use and increased
>   scrotum temperature—up to 35˚ in certain positions!
>
> This increase has a well-documented harmful effect on spermatogenesis
>   (the process of male gamete formation), so if you’re trying to
>   conceive, leave the laptop on the desk.

What evidence is there to support or contradict this claim?

Comment: Are you wanting to purchase the mat if it does, or if it doesn't?

Comment: @PeterOfTheCorn, Think of the preventative usage savings!

Comment: Note that you didn't ask the better question: does using a laptop mat increase my sperm quality w.r.t. not using it? Because otherwise, the best strategy would be: use a table :-)

Comment: Even Better question:  If the Catholic Church is against birth control, should they ban the use of laptops?  :)

Answer (score 28):

Yes,

This wonderful article, [Increase in scrotal temperature in laptop computer users](http://humrep.oxfordjournals.org/content/20/2/452.short) in the Oxford Journals of Human Reproduction explains it nicely. So the heat that the laptop generates does lower your sperm count.

**EDIT**
As pointed out by Solus, I didn't show that higher scrotal temperature decrease the sperm quality. So here is a study from 2002 that I found on NCBI called [Impact of diurnal scrotal temperature on semen quality.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12128094) that shows it.

Comment: And there I was thinking it was correlation without causation!

Comment: The abstract reports a change in scrotal temperature, not a drop in sperm count. It also reports a significant rise in temp even without using a laptop. 2.1C without, vs 2.6-2.8C with. So 2 points: 1) you need to cite other research to support the link between temp & sperm count (or just cite their citation), and 2) just sitting raises temps, so while laptops don't help, you're not necessarily safe without the laptop.

Comment: @Solus 1) you are absolutely right, will do when I can latter today. Thanks! 2)you are never safe (IMHO)

Comment: @Zenon: you are not, however, considering the time variable. The 2002 articles speaks about median temperature during the day: using your laptop 30' on your lap before going to bad is different than, say, using it for 8 hours straight...

Comment: It should be noted that it's the *temperature* that is relevant, not the laptop use. If you consistently have something hot sitting on your lap, you will have the same issues no matter what it is.

Comment: @Zenon I often put laptop on chest when lying in bed, does this present risk for sperm quality? also will using blanket between chest and laptop lower risk?