# Does frequent cell phone use reduce the sperm count of men?

Tags: medical-science, radiation, mobile-phones, fertility, sperm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the presence of a cellphone affect sperm count or heart rate?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/does-the-presence-of-a-cellphone-affect-sperm-count-or-heart-rate)

Is cell phone use harmless or is there a chance that it lowers the sperm count of men?

> New independent studies offer proof
>   that confirms findings from the
>   Council of Europe: pulsed digital
>   signals from cell phones disrupt DNA,
>   impair brain function, and **lower
>   sperm count**, according to a
>   statement by the Environmental Health
>   Trust (EHT).
>   [(source)](http://www.kurzweilai.net/new-studies-reveal-evidence-that-cell-phone-radiation-damages-dna-brain-and-sperm)

Comment: I'd put up with disrupted DNA and impaired brain function, but hell will freeze over before I let anything reduce my sperm count :-D 
(Funny that this part gets emphasized)

FWIW, this claim is also made by Tim Ferriss in his book "The 4-hour body", which, I fear, might be a rich source of questions for this site.

Comment: Related:  [Does using a laptop on your lap lower your sperm count?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/does-using-a-laptop-on-your-lap-lower-your-sperm-count)

Comment: Closing as a duplicate. While this is older, the other question is more general (and has answers) :-)