# Does keeping phone in the front pocket cause male infertility?

Tags: radiation, mobile-phones, fertility

According to this [article](https://www.thehealthy.com/skin-health/places-you-should-never-keep-your-phone/#:%7E:text=In%20your%20pocket&text=According%20to%20Lilly%20Friedman%2C%20MD,or%20holster%2C%E2%80%9D%20she%20says.) supposedly keeping your smartphone in the front pocket can cause infertility in men.

> According to Lilly Friedman, MD, this is actually the worst place to
> store your cell phone. “When cell phones are on, connected to a
> wireless network, and placed in a pocket, the radiation is two to
> seven times higher than if it were placed in a purse or holster,” she
> says.
>
> Plus, radiation can change the structure of DNA and **affect male
> fertility**,

She didn't provide any reference so it seems more like an opinion.
Was there any studies done on men's infertility for those who carry phones like this?

I don't know where else can anyone comfortable carry their phone if not in the front pocket.

**Note:** I know there is a similar [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/does-the-presence-of-a-cellphone-affect-sperm-count-or-heart-rate) already asked but that was in **2011** and at that time hardly many people had smartphones. Plus more studies might have been done.

Comment: The article does link to an inconclusive [study](https://ascopubs.org/doi/pdfdirect/10.1200/JCO.2008.21.6366) about tumors dated 2009. The argument about dangers from cell phone radiation has been going on a long time, often with regard to the masts themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the presence of a cellphone affect sperm count or heart rate?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/does-the-presence-of-a-cellphone-affect-sperm-count-or-heart-rate)

Comment: @JoeW if you read my question you would know it doesn't!

Comment: You can add a bounty to that question to ask for newer answers with new information and we don't need duplicate questions asked over time as that leads to information being spread out across the site and harder to find.

Comment: @JoeW, my question is different though. The lower sperm count doesn't necessarily mean infertility.

Comment: You should explain why your question is different instead of stating that the existing question and answers are outdated. Duplicate questions should not be asked because the existing answers are outdated.

Comment: I have to reject the idea that "hardly anyone" had phones carried in pockets in 2011. [1.5 billion](https://mobiforge.com/research-analysis/2011-handset-and-smartphone-sales-statistics-worldwide-big-picture) (with a b!) mobile phones were sold that year alone.

Comment: Re *I don't know where else can anyone comfortable carry their phone if not in the front pocket.* A lot of women carry their cellphones in their purses rather than their front pockets. (Their clothing oftentimes does not even have pockets.) That said not many males carry purses. We might carry backpacks or briefcases, but not all day long. BTW, my cellphone is in my front pocket right now.

Comment: @Oddthinking: the OP was speaking about smartphones, not cellphones in general. Not sure the difference matters for the question though.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between "alter fertility" (so vague it can almost mean anything) and "infertility" (which probably has a clear, precise medical definition)

Comment: @Oddthinking The question literally mentions _smart_ phones, which really were much less universal in 2011 than they're now, but that doesn't matter. There's no practical difference between the radio parts of a smart and a dumb phone, hence also no difference in emissions. The only thing making a smartphone smart is a more powerful CPU, more RAM and storage, and mainly a different OS. None of those has any effect on RF emissions.

Comment: Re "I don't know where else can anyone comfortable carry their phone if not in the front pocket." I can't actually get my Galaxy smartphone into my jeans front pockets, and if I did I wouldn't be able to sit down. I put it in the back pocket.

Comment: @TooTea since smartphones have more powerful CPU, I would expect the radiation/range too. The smartphones also have wifi, nfs and other type of transmission.

Comment: @RedSonja, I was mostly talking about men.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The article provides no evidence for the claim.

While there is some evidence linking cell phones to specific types of cancer, her claim that putting your phone in your pocket puts you at higher risk is a non-sequitur, and the FDA agrees about the lack of evidence.

The authors of her referenced paper state...

> ...these findings should not be directly extrapolated to human cell phone usage.

The [FDA states](https://www.fda.gov/radiation-emitting-products/cell-phones/scientific-evidence-cell-phone-safety) that...

> To date, there is no consistent or credible scientific evidence of health problems caused by the exposure to radio frequency energy emitted by cell phones

They cite [Review of Published Literature between 2008 and 2018 of Relevance to Radiofrequency Radiation and Cancer](https://www.fda.gov/media/135043/download).

## Who is "Lilly Friedman, MD"?

The referenced article is a cut & paste, with minor edits and mistakes.

The [original article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/four-reason-you-should-never-keep-your-phone-pocket-lily-friedman/) was by [*Lily* Friedman, *MC*](https://www.linkedin.com/in/lily-friedman-a5a35411/), a Doctor of [Chiropractic Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiropractic) at Comprehensive Wellness Institute which she owns. Chiropractors are not MDs (Doctor of Medicine), but MCs (Doctor of Chiropractic). They're also generally not cancer experts.

## What does she claim?

She claims that "*when cell phones are on, connected to wireless network, and placed in a pocket, the radiation is 2-7 times higher than if it were placed in a purse or holster*" nor that "*radiation can change the structure of DNA and affect male fertility*", but provides no sources for these claims.

"Radiation" is so vague to be meaningless. When most people hear "radiation" they think [ionizing radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation), very high energies which can strip electrons from molecules associated with nuclear power. However, sunlight, microwaves, heat, and radio waves are all lower energy ["radiation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation).

She provides a source for one claim that "*there is a direct correlation between the radiation from a cell phone and tumor growth*" which we'll go into below.

Most importantly, [***she provides no connection between her claims and her conclusions***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_fallacy).

## What does the paper actually say?

Dr. Friedman references a Scientific American article [*Major Cell Phone Radiation Study Reignites Cancer Questions*](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/major-cell-phone-radiation-study-reignites-cancer-questions/) which is about [a report](https://ntp.niehs.nih.gov/whatwestudy/topics/cellphones/index.html) from the [National Toxicology Program](https://ntp.niehs.nih.gov/). [Here is a handy summary](https://www.niehs.nih.gov/health/materials/cell_phone_radiofrequency_radiation_studies_508.pdf).

The report does find an increase of 1% to 3% in specific tumors ***in rats exposed to 2G and 3G radiation over their entire bodies for their entire lives***.

[The FDA takes issue with attempting to relate this to public health](https://www.fda.gov/radiation-emitting-products/cell-phones/scientific-evidence-cell-phone-safety)...

> The conclusions relating to public health risks reached by the FDA’s scientists differ from those of the NTP, and the FDA determination is that the study did not demonstrate that cell phones cause cancer.
>
> 5 Facts About the Rat Study
>
> 1. Rats received radiation over their entire bodies.
> 2. Rats received this whole-body radiation for 9 hours per day for their entire lives.
> 3. Rats received levels of radiation that were up to 75 times higher than the whole-body exposure limit for people.
> 4. The study found no health effects on female rats or mice (both male and female) exposed to these extreme conditions that passed a test for statistical significance.
> 5. Exposed rats lived longer than the control group rats.
>
> The design did not reflect the partial-body radio frequency exposure people receive from cell phone use and as noted by the NTP in their February 2018 press release:
>
> "The levels and duration of exposure to RFR were much greater than what people experience with even the highest level of cell phone use and exposed the rodents’ whole bodies. So, ***these findings should not be directly extrapolated to human cell phone usage***."

Comment: I think the claim that "radiation can change the structure of DNA and affect male fertility" is very well established and needs no further citation. Note that this does not claim "radiation from cell phones", but "radiation" in general, which includes ionizing radiation. Could be misleading though to conflate cell phone radiation with ionizing radiation.

Comment: @laolux: "Radiation" without further qualification is so broad as to be a meaningless claim.

Comment: "Radiation" is such a scary word because many people associate it with ionizing radiation, and don't know the difference. But visible light is also the same electromagnetic radiation as gamma rays, x-rays and microwaves, just with a different frequency. However, those who practice alternative medicine and want to scare people, are eager to jump on the bandwagon of "radiation = scary"

Comment: Radiation (such as sunlight) can cause cancer!  I agree that the term "radiation" is of no use in this claim.

Comment: Thanks all, I've done an edit to explain "radiation".